# TeamCity is not able to get BitBucket tag

Tags: gradle, teamcity, bitbucket, git-tag

I have a build.gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //some repo

        dependencies {
            classpath "com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.8.0"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.palantir.git-version'
version contructSemVer()

def contructSemVer() {
    try {
        def details = versionDetails()
        def semVer = details.lastTag + "-" + details.branchName + "." + details.gitHash
    }
    catch (ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Following `gradle-git-version` plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version), I construct a `semVer` string for the version. I then tagged my BitBucket with **0.1.0** on a branch **test-gradle**.

Upon calling `gradle properties | findstr version` locally on my IntelliJ, I got the correct output: `version: 0.1.0-test-gradle.52cb23e4a0`

However, when running the same thing on TeamCity, the first part (`details.lastTag`) of `semVer` is missing, the version I got is `-test-gradle.52cb23e4a0` It seems that TeamCity is unable to pickup the BitBucket tag, but can pickup branch name and latest commit SHA.

Is there any settings in TeamCity that I miss? Thanks and let me know if you need more details

Comment: I guess this depends on your TeamCity settings and is hard to tell without seeing them. I guess that the tag is not available on the clone where you build and thus cannot be seen by that plugin.

Comment: In `Edit VCS Root` setting, I checked `Use tags as branches` box. Also in `Branch Specification`, I put `+:refs/heads/*` so it should monitor all branches. Also, the tag is visible on **test-gradle** branch that TeamCity is building.

Comment: I have no experience with Git and TeamCity, but the description of the checkbox for me means that you can use tag refs in that input field, not that the tags are made branches or not necessarily that they are fetched on the agent.

Comment: Btw. sometimes it is easier to simply Google for your problem instead of asking here. https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205450030-TeamCity-Git-Agent-Checkout-does-not-pull-new-tags- probably helps you.

Comment: The thing is TeamCity can pickup `details.branchName` and `details.gitHash`. What do you think are the possible causes? I'll edit build as you say and let you know the result

Comment: I tried that, remove all in `Branch Specification`, unchecked `Use Mirrors`. Still didn't work :(

Comment: As I say, I have not much xp with Git and TeamCity and I don't know the `git-version` plugin, but from what you wrote I'd guess it deteremines the last tag which would mean that the clone on the build agent does not have the tag available. You could log into the build agent and verify the used clone as to whether tags are present or not and then find out how to configure TeamCity to have the Tag available. Btw. IMHO, it is a very bad practice to use dynamic VCS during a build, as you then never can build a project properly without the VCS being available, e. g. from an export or a sources ZIP.

Comment: I'd at the very most would have a dedicated task that retrieves information and writes them to a file that you then can check into VCS. Only maybe the SHA or similar could be determined dynamically to have unique versions for continuous builds, but not to have it somewhere meaningful, but just as additional information. But that is just my 2ct.

Comment: Try setting parameter `teamcity.git.fetchAllHeads = true`. I had a similar, although not identical, problem.  HTH.

Comment: Where do you have this from? I don't see it on https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Git#Git-InternalProperties

Comment: @Vampire buried in a youtrack ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24878#comment=27-1746765

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more attempts at different TeamCity settings, I tried another method to get the latest Git Tag

```
def contructSemVer() {
    try {
        def details = versionDetails()
        def semVer = getVersionFromTag() + "-" + details.branchName + "." + details.gitHash
    }
    catch (ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}

def getVersionFromTag() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--abbrev=0'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

So instead of using `details.lastTag`, I'm using my own method to retrieve it. It is shown correctly in TeamCity build now.

Thanks also to @Vampire for shedding much lights on many TeamCity settings